# NojeJs + ApiGoogle Subir archivos con otro nombre

Tags: nodejs

Hola estoy tratando de subir a Google Drive mediante la api de Google en NodeJs, los archivos me lo sube perfectamente pero necesito anteponerle un nombre "FrenteDNI" al primer archivo y al segundo "DorsoDNI". Cuando subo los archivos me sube perfectamente pero no me deja cambiarle el nombre dejo el codigo de app.js.

```
  **CODIGO APP.JS**

    >   var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    >         destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    >             var dir = 'G:/Mi unidad/prueba';
    >             if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
    >                 fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    >             }
    >             callback(null, dir);
    >         },
    >         filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    >             callback(null, file.originalname);
    >         }
    >     });

>     
>     var upload = multer({storage: storage})
>     app.post('/upload', upload.array('dni', 2), (req, res) => {
>         req.files.forEach((file) => {
>             const inputValue = req.body.inputValue;
>             const fileMetadata = {
>                 name: `FrenteDNI-${inputValue}.jpg`
>             };
>             const media = {
>                 mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
>                 body: fs.createReadStream(file.path)
>             };
>             
>             drive.files.create({
>                 resource: fileMetadata,
>                 media: media,
>                 fields: 'id'
>             }, (err, file) => {
>                 if (err) throw err;
>                 console.log(`File ID: FrenteDNI-${file.data.id}`);
>             });
>         });
>        
>         res.send('Archivos subidos exitosamente!');
>     });
```

**CODIGO HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Node.js Simple File Upload</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dvh.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
</head>
<body>
 
    <div class="container">
      
        <form action="/upload" class="form-control" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <label class="form-label">Nombre y Apellido</label>
          <br>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="inputValue" id="inputValue">
          
          <div class="form-control">
            <label class="form-label">Suba su DNI Frente</label>
            <br>
            <input type="file" name="dni" multiple required >
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="form-control">
              <label class="form-label">Suba su DNI Dorso</label>
              <br>
              <input type="file" name="dni" multiple required >
              </div>
           <hr>
            <button class="btn btn-success" style="border-radius: 4px;display: block;" type="submit" style="border-radius: 4px;">
                Upload
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
  
    

</body>
<script>
    const input = document.getElementById("inputValue");
  input.addEventListener("input", function() {
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
  });

</script>
</html>
```

El html es muy simple es subir los archivos y nada mas.
Dejo muestra de que se suben perfectamente los archivos a google drive a la carpeta que tengo compartida.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

texto informativo
texto informativo
texto informativo
texto informativo
texto informativo
texto informativo

Answer (score 1):

Cuando ejecutes el método 'create' en vez introducir la clave 'resource' ingresa 'requestBody' de modo que te quede lo siguiente:

```
drive.files.create({
    requestBody: fileMetadata,
    ...
})
```

Es algo que debería corregir de la documentación que se encuentra en su sitio: [Fuente](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#media-uploads)

Answer (score 1):

Agrega en *name* en *fields* usa *requestBody* y si usas carpeta compartida usa *supportsAllDrives* en **true** :

```
.....
drive.files.create({
              requestBody: fileMetadata,
              media: media,
              fields: 'id, name',
              supportsAllDrives:true,
              }.......
```